# Tracing old transactions with Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transaction-trace

I have a node synched in normal mode up until `number=5143444`

Node started with

```
geth --datadir "./"
--rpc 
--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 
--ws 
--wsaddr 0.0.0.0 
--wsorigins="*" 
--maxpeers 100 
--maxpendpeers 10 
console
```

I'm trying to test the geth traces (compared to parity traces) but it seems I cannot get old transactions.

I've tried running trace on a recent transaction and it works

```
> debug.traceTransaction("0x59ae735c0291ec79460968d01dbd5b4adf007571bfaa308b8ab1005bb5e3f500")
{
  failed: false,
  gas: 21000,
  returnValue: "",
  structLogs: []
}
```

But if I try running trace on an older transaction (from block `1580796`), I get this

```
> debug.traceTransaction("0x8e5b38db03e0941677ba65275d78fe18df999c11a7be1921831082121ae73390")
Error: required historical state unavailable
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I know with `parity` I need to specifically set `tracing` and `archive` on:

```
--tracing=on
--pruning=archive
```

And this creates a HUGE database. Is there something similar for `geth`?
The [command line options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) don't seem to have anything about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have available all of the information you need to sync your node with `--syncmode full`

Comment: Hi there, I tried the following command but still got the same error: `geth --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug" console --syncmode full`. Any idea on that?

Comment: Was the node fully synchronized when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I use `eth.syncing` to check the current block, then check a block that is order than the current one.

Comment: this answer is incorrect. You need archival node to trace old transactions. Full node only tracks 128 states in memory and some trace log info to be able to reconstruct few weeks of old states. But a transaction year old won't traceable because states are pruned.

Answer (score 2):

You must set gcmode=archive when start geth.

Comment: this is the correct answer. Though as of today you need 8 Terabytes of SSD storage to have archival node. One could get help from `bcache` and use 1GB SSD disk with 8TB backing device